# Definir o tamanho do retorno do campo

Tags: sql, informix

Tenho um sql:

```
Select a.nome

From tabela a
```

Quero retornar o nome, mas imagine que meu campo nome tenha tamanho Varchar(100), porem quero retornar os 50 primeiros caracteres.

**Edit:** É para informix da IBM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode-se usar a função **SUBSTRING**.

```
SELECT substring(a.nome from 1 for 50) FROM Tabela a
```

Comment: Não funciona para informix

Comment: Consegui, porem é outra sintaxe, altera a resposta e eu aceito ela: `SELECT substring(a.nome from 1 for 50) FROM Tabela a`

Comment: So close. Nem vi a Tag Informix. Mals...